# Opencart product path "$product['href']" doesnt work

Tags: opencart, href, product

In my opencart project my `$product['href']` is 
"index.php?route=product/product&path=60&product_id=81"
when i get to the page it only shows array() on the page.

if i then remove "&path=60" It shows the product..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can edit link generation in product controller in path

> /catalog/controller/product/product.php

search for

> `'href'        => $this->url->link

in default should be: 
`'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']),`

if it doesn't same as default so edit it.